# How to properly do smooth speed degradation?

Tags: c++, sfml

at the moment I'm using this:

```
playerclass.xspeed += (playerclass.xvelocity * loopclock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds());
to build up speed
```

To ramp up speed

and this:

```
if (playerclass.xspeed > 0||(playerclass.xspeed < 0)){playerclass.xspeed *= (1-loopclock.restart().asSeconds());}
```

To degrade it.

It looks pretty smooth to me but the speed will never reach zero, just get smaller and smaller infinitely

Setting the speed to zero if it's ever below a certain bound doesn't work because my speed builds up in very small amounts.

New to programming so apologies if this is an obvious answer.

Comment: "Setting the speed to zero if it's ever below a certain bound doesn't work because my speed builds up in very small amounts." set the threshold lower.

Comment: @John I'm going to delete this post out of shame

Comment: did that answer your question? No need to delete if it helps answer somebody else's question in the future.

Comment: @John good point, can't believe I didn't think of this though